# Color x , y Plotbands highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, ionic2

Is it a way to color a squared plotbands, for exemple from 0 to 1 on x and from 9 to 10 on y? 
I want to color every 10 points on x, from 0 to 10, from 10 to 20 , same color on negative, mirror effect, but y has to be negative,from 0 to -10.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code or make a live example with your data? What type of chart do you use?The picture  you have posted, is it what you want or what you already have?

Comment: Is what I already done. I want from 0 to -10 on y to have different colors for every 10 step on x, for example for 0 to -20/20 on x have green then from 20/-20 tp 40/-40 have yellow, only on y<0

Comment: You can renderer rectangles and put them as background in the chart with the use of the renderer - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.rect To calculate their position you can use axis.toPixels() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.toPixels

Answer (score 0):

You can use polygons to shade over certain areas of the graph that plotBands cannot.

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/qhtec334/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        name: 'Polygons',
        type: 'polygon',
        data: [
            [2, 100],
            [3, 100],
            [3, 200],
            [2, 200],
            null, // allows multiple polygons         
            [6, 100],
            [8, 100],
            [8, 200],
            [6, 200]
        ]
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```